# Excel VBA - Filter data that is locked with password

Tags: excel, vba, filter, locked

I've been stuck for days on the following:

I'd like to lock data with a password in specific rows and then still be able to use a filter on this data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjv0j.png)

This is what i got so far but for some reason it does not work.

Any input would be very welcome!!!

```
If logbook.Cells(row_index, 1) <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect password:="mypassword"
    logbook.Cells(row_index, 11).Value = "YES"
    logbook.Cells(row_index, 1).EntireRow.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect password:="mypassword", AllowFiltering:=True         
Else
    Unload Me
End If
```

Comment: `AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True` add these to `ActiveSheet.Protect` to enable sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the data through VBA, you dont need to unprotect it.

Simply use UserInterfaceOnly:=True and by using AllowFiltering:=True you can still filter your data. Like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="mypassword", AllowFiltering:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, but this works:

```
Sub Test()

    'worksheet is protected
    'read only operations

    Sheets("tbl").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"

    'changes to worksheet

    Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="mypassword"

End Sub
```

Comment: When the sheet is completely protected, I am not able to filter the data. So I need to find a way to protect the sheet and at the same time allow the user to filter the data.

Comment: Protected sheets cannot be altered as far as I know. Either read out the data you need and manipulate it somwhere else, or lift protection for data manipulation.